# Call set state of FirstScreen from SecondScreen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have two screens in flutter named 'FirstScreen' with list of orders and 'SecondScreen' for certain actions.

I would like to call setstate of 'FirstScreen' on 'SecondScreen' pop, so that the 'FirstScreen' will reload list of pending orders[image: FirstScreen]

SecondScreen will accept or reject orders and it FirstScreen should reload data from server, which is called by method getOrders() in FirstScreen.
[image: SecondScreen]

FirstScreen Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/model/jobOrderItem.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/screens/SeconScreen.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstScreenState createState() => FirstScreenState();
}
class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {

  Future<List<JobOrders>> _getPendingOrder() async {
    var data = await http.get("$ApiServer/JobOrders/smOrdersPending");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<JobOrders> joborderitemlist = [];
    for (var i in jsonData) {
      JobOrders jobOrders = JobOrders(
        Eid: i["Eid"],
        Uid: i["Uid"],
        Name: i["Name"],
        Contact: i["Contact"].toString(),
        OrderStat: i["OrderStat"],
      );
      joborderitemlist.add(jobOrders);
    }
    return joborderitemlist;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FirstScreen'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getPendingOrder(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.data.length <= 0) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('You have not made any orders yet...'),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return OrdersListWidget(
                    Eid: snapshot.data[index].Eid,
                    Uid: snapshot.data[index].Uid.toString(),
                    Name: snapshot.data[index].Name.toString(),
                    Contact: snapshot.data[index].Contact.toString(),
                    Status: snapshot.data[index].OrderStat.toString(),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
class OrdersListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int Eid;
  String Uid;
  String Name;
  String Contact;
  String Status;
  OrdersListWidget(
      {@required this.Eid,
        @required this.Uid,
        @required this.Name,
        @required this.Contact,
        @required this.Status});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Text('#$Eid'),
          title: Text(Name),
          subtitle: Text(Contact),
          trailing: Text(Status),
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  child: SecondScreen(OrderId: Eid),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

SecondScreen Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/model/orderItem.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:nobleappshop/widgets/iconTextWidget.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/widgets/scOrderItems.dart';
import 'package:nobleappshop/constants/constants.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  int OrderId;
  SecondScreen({@required this.OrderId});

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

  Future<http.Response> _updateJobOrder() async {
//Run Update code here
  }
  double totalAmount = 0;
  String token;

  List<OrderItem> orderitemlist = [];

  Future<List<OrderItem>> _getMyOrders() async {
//Call for orderitemslist
    return orderitemlist;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMyOrders();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[

            IconTextRowWidget(btnIcon: Icons.credit_card,btnText: 'Amount Due',btnSubText: '${totalAmount<10?10:totalAmount} QAR',),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onPressed: (){
                      // Here I would like to close my current screen and reload orderslist, so that it will load all other pending joborders
                      _updateJobOrder();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('Approve',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: (){
// Here I would like to close my current screen and reload orderslist, so that it will load all other pending joborders
                      _updateJobOrder();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('Reject',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,)
//            SizedBox(
//              height: 30.0,
//            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I checked your code I realized that you need to send function to the grandchild of your first widget,

1. You need to declare a function in your `OrdersListWidget` because this widget is only way to access the second screen.

```dart
    class OrdersListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      int Eid;
      String Uid;
      String Name;
      String Contact;
      String Status;
      final VoidCallback setStateOfFirstScreen;
    
      OrdersListWidget(
          {@required this.Eid,
          @required this.Uid,
          @required this.Name,
          @required this.Contact,
          @required this.Status,
          @required this.setStateOfFirstScreen});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Text('#$Eid'),
              title: Text(Name),
              subtitle: Text(Contact),
              trailing: Text(Status),
              onTap: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                      child: SecondScreen(OrderId: Eid, setStateOfFirstScreen: setStateOfFirstScreen),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Divider(),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

2. And send setState to the `OrdersListWidget` as a parameter in your first page;

```dart
    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return OrdersListWidget(
          Eid: snapshot.data[index].Eid,
          Uid: snapshot.data[index].Uid.toString(),
          Name: snapshot.data[index].Name.toString(),
          Contact: snapshot.data[index].Contact.toString(),
          Status: snapshot.data[index].OrderStat.toString(),
          setStateOfFirstScreen: () => setState(() {}),
        );
      },
    );
```

3. Send the `setStateOfFirstScreen`  to the `SecondScreen` and use it there to setState of the first screen;

```dart
    class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final int OrderId;
      final VoidCallback setStateOfFirstScreen;
    
      SecondScreen({@required this.OrderId, @required this.setStateOfFirstScreen});
    
      @override
      _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
      Future<http.Response> _updateJobOrder() async {
    //Run Update code here
      }
      double totalAmount = 0;
      String token;
    
      List<OrderItem> orderitemlist = [];
    
      Future<List<OrderItem>> _getMyOrders() async {
    //Call for orderitemslist
        return orderitemlist;
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _getMyOrders();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Color(0xff757575),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconTextRowWidget(
                  btnIcon: Icons.credit_card,
                  btnText: 'Amount Due',
                  btnSubText: '${totalAmount < 10 ? 10 : totalAmount} QAR',
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Here I would like to close my current screen and reload orderslist, so that it will load all other pending joborders
                          _updateJobOrder();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          widget.setStateOfFirstScreen();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Approve',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        onPressed: () {
    // Here I would like to close my current screen and reload orderslist, so that it will load all other pending joborders
                          _updateJobOrder();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          widget.setStateOfFirstScreen();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Reject',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                )
    //            SizedBox(
    //              height: 30.0,
    //            ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time helping me and looking into it. I have done everything as mentioned, but setState is not firing. no error either

Comment: sorry, I missed to add () at the end of widget.setStateOfPendingOrders();  Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a void call back or a function as a property of second screen and send it from first screen; here is an example;

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback setStateOfFirstScreen;

  const SecondScreen({Key key, this.setStateOfFirstScreen}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.refresh), onPressed: setStateOfFirstScreen),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}

class FistScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FistScreenState createState() => _FistScreenState();
}

class _FistScreenState extends State<FistScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text("Go to the second screen"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (c) => SecondScreen(
                  setStateOfFirstScreen: () => setState(() {}),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. How can I achieve this when I am using my SecondScreen as a child of FirstScreen. I am using SecondScreen as BottomSheet for FirstScreen

Comment: Actually it's the same please, share your code example so I will be able to show you with edit your code.

Comment: @ malibayram91 please see the updated question with code